# Adding space to multiselect Zend Framework 1.12 Forms from XML

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, xml-parsing

I was wondering how can I add spaces for multiselect values when creating Zend forms from XML files.

Tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settingsinfo>
    <lp_form_label_font_family>
        <type>Select</type>
        <options>
            <label>Landing Page Form Label Font Family</label>
            <description>Landing Page Form Label Font Family</description>
            <multioptions>
                <option value="Open Sans">Open Sans</option>
                <option value="Droid Sans">Droid Sans</option>
                <option value="Sans Serif" >Sans Serif</option>
                <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
            </multioptions>
            <required></required>
        </options>           
    </lp_form_label_font_family>
</settingsinfo>
```

The above generates:

```
<dd id="lp_form_label_font_family-element">
<select name="lp_form_label_font_family" id="lp_form_label_font_family" class="described">
    <optgroup id="lp_form_label_font_family-optgroup-option" label="option">
    <option value="0">Open Sans</option>
    <option value="1">Droid Sans</option>
    <option value="2">Sans Serif</option>
    <option value="3">Arial</option>
    <option value="4">Helvetica</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<p class="description">Landing Page Form Label Font Family</p></dd>
```

---

Trying with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settingsinfo>
    <lp_form_label_font_family>
        <type>Select</type>
        <options>
            <label>Landing Page Form Label Font Family</label>
            <description>Landing Page Form Label Font Family</description>
            <multioptions>
                <OpenSans>Open Sans</OpenSans>
                <DroidSans>Droid Sans</DroidSans>
                <sans-serif>Sans Serif</sans-serif>
                <arial>Arial</arial>
                <helvetica>Helvetica</helvetica>
            </multioptions>
            <required></required>
        </options>
    </lp_form_label_font_family>
</settingsinfo>
```

Generates:

```
<dd id="lp_form_label_font_family-element">
<select name="lp_form_label_font_family" id="lp_form_label_font_family" class="described">
    <option value="OpenSans">Open Sans</option>
    <option value="DroidSans">Droid Sans</option>
    <option value="sans-serif">Sans Serif</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
</select>
<p class="description">Landing Page Form Label Font Family</p></dd>
```

---

Which is close enough, but I need the spaces for the values.

I really need to have eg:

```
<dd id="lp_form_label_font_family-element">
<select name="lp_form_label_font_family" id="lp_form_label_font_family" class="described">
    <option value="Open Sans">Open Sans</option>
    <option value="Droid Sans">Droid Sans</option>
    <option value="sans-serif">Sans Serif</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
</select>
<p class="description">Landing Page Form Label Font Family</p></dd>
```

Any clue on how to add spaces for the values of my font families? How should I change this XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to rebuid the options of the element like this:

```
$select = $form->getElement('lp_form_label_font_family');
$options = array();
foreach($form->getElement('lp_form_label_font_family')->getMultiOptions() as $option){
    $options[$option] = $option;
}
$form->getElement('lp_form_label_font_family')->setMultiOptions($options);
```

Comment: Thanks man. Unfortunately the reason that I am using the XML is for not rebuilding elements and automation. Cant add exceptions for every new element that is added on XML.

Comment: Maybe you could use arrays in php files to create Zend_Config instead of XML files. You win also performance. Otherwise I'm sorry, I have no other solutions :) Good Luck.

Comment: You are correct on that. Unfortunately my requirements are to get an external XML file. I wish I could just go with php arrays, but I can't.

Comment: You can try to use your own `My_View_Helper_FormSelect` and change the `_build` method